# extract multiple parts of a string with R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have two strings:

```
data = "Product Number: #76 in c (See Top 10 products in this department)"
data1 = "Product Number: #321,222 in Thin Base Pizzas (See Top 10 products in this department)"
```

using str_match() in R, what would be the regex for the following results?

> str_match(data, regex)
>        [,1]                   [,2] [,3]
>   [1,] "#76 in Fruit Juices " "76" "Fruit Juices "
>
> str_match(data1, regex)
>        [,1]                            [,2]      [,3]
>   [1,] "#321,222 in Thin Base Pizzas " "321,222" "Thin Base Pizzas "

Comment: more context please, need to find regularity in the structure of your strings to provide useful answer.

Comment: provide more detail

Comment: The number after # can have multiple digits and coma as a thousands separator ex: #31,123.
the text after "in" and before "(See" can vary in length but has no special characters Ex: "Thin base pizzas" Teh Text "Product Number: #" and the text "(See Top 10 products in this department)" never changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to extract the information you need:

```
#([0-9,]+) in ([A-z ]+)
```

you can see in action here: https://regex101.com/r/IM0wHV/1

Comment: Take care of the range `A-z`, it includes non letter characters `[`,  `]`,`^`,`_` , backslash and backquote

Answer (score 0):

Given your first comment I think this will generalize to give you the product number.

```
sub(" .*", "", sub(".*#", "", data))
"76"
```

And this second one will give you whatever is between the `in` and `(`.

```
sub(" \\(.*", "", sub(".*[0-9]+ in ", "", data))
"Fruit Juices"
```

Not an ideal solution but it's an working example you can take forward from here.